# Triggering Pig job with oozie

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, oozie

I have a java code with pig statements embedded inside using the `registerQuery()` method of the `PigServer` class. Now that I prepare a jar of it, I can run it as `hadoop jar jarname`, but the question is how can the same job be triggered using `oozie` scheduler. Though it is internally map reduce that works, we cannot call it a map reduce action. Similarly since it is not a pig action, we cannot set that too. Is it possible to run such a task with oozie? What is the best way to schedule such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you are trying to do is not part of Oozie's supported functionality. As your task is neither a typical Java Map Reduce nor a pig action you better off using crontab functionality provided by the operating system to schedule your job or use Spring scheduler.

There is a spring distribution for Hadoop also,  called [Spring Data - Apache Hadoop](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/hadoop) which provides a built-in scheduling functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was scheduling the task using crontab, just needed to make a cross check.

Answer (score 0):

The Oozie [MapReduce](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2_Map-Reduce_Action) action's purpose it to run jobs like 'hadoop jar...'.

The doc details it and some Hue [tutorials](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/60937985689/hadoop-tutorials-ii-2-execute-hive-queries-and) demo how to run the Oozie job.